# Accessing non-sync'd method of class when sync'd method is locked

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a synchronized method and a non-synchronized method in a class, and I have one thread that obtains a lock on the synchronized method.

My question is this: can other threads access the non-synchronized method of the class in this situation?

Comment: Only code which must hold the lock will be run one thread at a time. Code which can be run without the lock, can be run no matter if the object is locked or not.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The method remains accessible to other threads if it is not declared `synchronized`

Comment: But some thread was already put lock on that object right.., then how its possible for other thread to enter that locked object

Comment: No, it uses the lock to access the mathod. If any other thread tries to reuse the same lock, it gets stuck and waits for the other one to finish

Comment: but you said  The method remains accessible to other threads if it is not declared synchronized ?

Comment: Yes, if you don't specify a method `synchronized` then the other thread won't block and will have access to that method

Comment: Though we have lock on that class, other threads can access the normal methods right.. ?

Comment: Wait dosen't the object get locked ? So if the object is locked by thread 1 ... then thread 2 should not be able to access any method/variable of that object right ? Isnt that how synchronize works

Comment: Yes the object gets locked but remember: a second thread can always access that object as long as it does not pass by a `synchronized` block on the locked object

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, other threads can access non-synchronized methods, but do remember other threads can't access your other synchronized methods, because there is only one lock per object not per method.

Answer (score 1):

A synchronized method is only a syntactic shortcut for a synchronized block using the current instance as a monitor (lock):

```
public synchronized void abc() {
    //something to do
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public void abc() {
    synchronized(this) {
        //something to do
    }
}
```

To run a synchronized block, a thread must first acquire the corresponding monitor, in this case `this`, which guarantees that no more than one thread can run the block at the same time.

Now the fact that `this` is used as a monitor does not guarantee anything outside the synchronized block. In other words, if your object contains non-synchronized methods, they can be run concurrently by multiple threads as they don't require that the running threads acquire the `this` monitor.